# Mathematical formalism for the Many World's Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations

A short question: is there a mathematical formalism underlying the [Many Worlds  Interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation), that is published in the literature, in much the same way, but on a presumably smaller scale, as String Theory?

If there is, could anybody refer me to it, or a basic book or website that concentrates on the math, rather than any philosophical viewpoint?

Comment: [See here](http://www-tc.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/manyworlds/pdf/dissertation.pdf)

Comment: MWI is an interpretation, hence it's supposed to be identical to "ordinary" QM, by which most people mean the Copenhagen interpretation. Where MWI stumbles (and that's basically everywhere along the line of explaining classical physics as a thermodynamic average of QM) it keeps waving a giant foam hand. Math can't save you there, since it is not supposed to lead to different predictions. Please not that the string models do make predictions, it's just not obvious if any of them are within the realm of current experimental physics.

Comment: The link given by Count Iblis seems dead now, can be found archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200617030156/https://www-tc.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/manyworlds/pdf/dissertation.pdf).